# NGINX Rate Limiting Configuration Leading to 404 Error for Specific Route in Plesk-Managed CakePHP App

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, nginx-reverse-proxy, rate-limiting, plesk

I'm using Plesk 18 with NGINX as a proxy in front of Apache2 for a CakePHP application. I have set up rate limiting in my NGINX configuration `(/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)` with `limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=5r/s;`. I want to apply this rate limit specifically to a route /my/path, which is defined in CakePHP as follows: `$routes->connect('/my/path', ['controller' => 'My', 'action' => 'path']);`.

However, when I add the following additional NGINX directive in Plesk:

```
location /my/path {
    limit_req zone=mylimit burst=10 nodelay;
    proxy_pass https://PUBLIC-SERVER-IP:PORT;
}
```

I receive a 404 error for that route, which otherwise works fine without this NGINX configuration. My goal is to also eventually block IPs that exceed the rate limit for a specified duration. How can I correctly configure NGINX to apply rate limiting to this route without causing a 404 error, ensuring requests are properly forwarded to Apache?

Comment: Voting to move to a different area as Plesk, like most management UI packages, does funky, Plesk-specific things to the server config.